# How to check whether it a test running under AVA, or in normal env

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, ava

I'm using AVA to run my tests. I use a config.js file at the root and I'd like it to be different when running test units. For example the path to the databases, in production `~/.app/data.db` would be `/tmp/<randomid>/data.db` while testing. With mocha I'd just check for `it` existence but here I can't

Answer (score 1):

I am using the NODE_ENV variable to load different configs for production, staging and development. Works like a charm.

Read this article to get you started with a nice setup: http://eng.datafox.co/nodejs/2014/09/28/nodejs-config-best-practices/